# Use Laravel Html and Form facades inside standalone view package

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, view

I have a legacy PHP project that I'm working on bringing some framework components into.  I'm starting by bringing Laravel's standalone View package into it.  I've used the following to get the Views in and functional inside my legacy project:

https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/blob/master/components/view/index.php

The views are working fine, but I'd like to use Laravel's Html and Form packages (https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/blob/master/components/view/index.php) in my views as well.  I've included "laravelcollective/html" in my composer.json file, but I'm not sure how to make it work with the standalone Views package.

Eventually, I will rewrite the legacy system using a framework from the start, but for now, I'd like like to bring a couple pieces into it.

Just to reiterate, I'm not trying to bring Html and Forms into the full Laravel installation (I know how to do that).  I'm just looking to bring that functionality into the standalone Views package to use with the legacy system.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found a package to handle it for 5.1...  https://packagist.org/packages/philo/laravel-blade

Comment: I don't have an issue with blade/views.  I just want to be able to use Html and Form components inside them.  Like <?php echo Html::text('input', 'value'); ?>.  The Html and Form parts are Laravel facades that need to be setup to be used.  I'm just not sure how to set them up inside a standalone component.

Comment: the current laravelcollective ones use the laravel FACDE/providers  process, so you would need to hook into this which will be a lot more work , so woudl just be best to port it all into a lravel / lumen project

Comment: Any idea how I would go about hooking into the facade/providers process for it?  Porting it over to a new Laravel project will take months, which I will most likely eventually do, but I'd still like to get this standalone piece in place before I go down that road.